# Using Docker container(s) for "narrow" integration test

Tags: docker, unit-testing

I am working in an environment where "system" test are absolutely dominant. Now for some functionalities, I would like to use pytest but with Docker containers spawned to host DB/GPG/email and similar services. My thought is to use them as "TestDoubles". Is this intention good? I really am not comfortable to test stuff like GPG and anything operating on file-system, mingling with users and similar on host where tests are performed.

Final goal would be to have 3 groups of tests:

1. unit
2. narrow integration (Docker here as fixture dependency)
3. system

Or maybe it would be better idea to use Docker as "system" tests, mimicking production environment as close as possible?

Any thoughts?

Best regards

Comment: That seems fine; do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @DavidMaze System I am working on is very tightly coupled and made up of a bunch of integrations which we glue together. However, it is very hard to test, so was thinking if I can start taking some services, like SMTP, static file serving, GPG and similar in Docker.

For the sake of the argument, lets say I want to test SMTP. I can do some TestSpy and record what I tried to send. As a bonus (or an alternative maybe, not sure), I would like to run Docker image with the same name as "production" email server and somehow (not yet sure how) check if emails are received by server.